# Polymer not working in Chrome (working in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, polymer, web-component

I'm running windows 7 with Firefox 43.0.1 and Chrome 47.0.2526.106 m

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Polymer tutorial</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="hello-world.html" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <hello-world name="Joe"></hello-world>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the component is

```
<dom-module id="hello-world">
  <template>
    <h1>Hello, User</h1>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "hello-world"
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Chrome refuses to render. Firefox has no probs.

I installed polymer by typing `bower install polymer` at the command line. bower.json says it's version `1.2.3`

Comment: "refuses to render", giving any reason why? Any error?

Comment: Maybe check the developer console output for errors?

Answer (score 1):

Try importing Polymer Library in the  component's file like shown below,

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Polymer tutorial</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script> 
    <link rel="import" href="hello-world.html" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <hello-world name="Joe"></hello-world>
  </body>
</html>
```

Component

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" />

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Polymer tutorial</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" />
    <link rel="import" href="hello-world.html" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <hello-world name="Joe"></hello-world>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Polymer tutorial</title>
    <script src="./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script> 
    <link rel="import" href="./hello-world.html" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <hello-world name="Joe"></hello-world>
  </body>
</html>
```

hello-world.html

```
<link rel="import" href="./bower_components/polymer/polymer.html" />

<dom-module id="hello-world">
  <template>
    <h1>Hello, User</h1>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "hello-world"
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```